# Why the integral of a cdf is convex?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to prove that the function
$$\Psi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x F_X(z)\, dz$$
where $F_X$ is the distribution function of an integrable random variable $X$, is convex. I have used the definition of a convex function unsuccessfully. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: A simple scenario would be that if $X$ had a pdf , then $\frac{d^{2}\psi}{dx^{2}}=f(x)\geq 0$

Comment: $F_X$ is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
Let $-\infty<y<x<t$, I want to prove that
$$\frac{\int_y^x F_X(z)\,dz}{x-y}\leq \frac{\int_x^t F_X(z)\,dz}{t-x}.$$

$$\frac{\int_y^x F_X(z)\,dz}{x-y}\leq F_X(x)=\frac{\int_x^t F_X(x)\,dz}{t-x}\leq \frac{\int_x^t F_X(z)\,dz}{t-x},$$
so the proof is completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think so, why?

Comment: Because you write “I want to prove that…”. Did you prove it or not?

Comment: Yes, I thought it was obvious...